# Unit Process: Order of Convergence

Tags: asymptotics, regression, random-walk

[image]

Hi!

I am currently learning about unit root processes (eg random walks) in my class.

I am having trouble understanding how to define the scaling matrix for the rate of convergence of the regression coefficients in a regression w/ a constant term on a nonstationary random walk (equation 2).

I am confused how the order rates of convergence was identified in the matrix form of the OLS statistics in the last equation (labeled 26). 
Obviously the element $(1,1)$ in $(X'X)^{-1}$ converges at rate $n$ but how do you know the rate of convergence for the other terms?

-Thank you!

Comment: May I ask from what textbook is this presentation?